# Did "interpolare" mean "polish up" or "polish among"? Why wasn't sup- used?

Tags: etymology, prefix

1. Does *inter-* mean "up" as Ayto vouches below? Is [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=interpolate) wrong that *inter-* means "among, between"?
2. Why didn't Latin use *sup-*, the prefix for "up", here?

> #### interpolate [17]

> The Latin ancestor of
> *interpolate* meant literally ‘polish up’. It was
> *interpolāre*, based on a verbal element *-polāre*
> that was related to *polīre* ‘polish’ (source of
> English polish). Its meaning gradually
> progressed metaphorically via ‘refurbish’ and
> ‘alter the appearance of’ to ‘falsify, particularly
> by the insertion of new material’ (this last
> presumably arising from a reassertion of the
> central meaning of *inter-*, ‘between’). English
> originally took it over in the sense ‘alter, tamper
> with’, but before the middle of the 17th century
> the notion of ‘insertion, interjection’ had begun
> to emerge in its own right, and has gradually
> taken over from ‘alter’.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 290 Left column.

[image]

*Oxford Latin Dictionary* 2012 2 edn, p 1040 Right column.

Comment: Ok, why the downvotes? It's an honest question!

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you inferring that **inter-** means *up*, from the meanings *touch up, work up*, etc.? If so, I think those are idiomatic to English. (There's nothing above, raising, or superior in touching up or working up.)

Comment: Ayto says very clearly in your own quoted passage that *inter-* means 'between'.

Comment: @Rafael I didn't down vote, but it's a really sloppy question that shows no real effort to find an answer before coming here.